# How to set up the DbContext in xUnit test project properly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, xunit

I have the following code to set up DBContext in the .Net core 2.0 console program and it's injected to the constructor of the main application class.

```
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = GetConfiguration();
    services.AddSingleton(configuration);
    Conn = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr1");

    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Conn));
```

Now I created a xUnit test class and need to initialize the same DbContext for testing.

```
    context = new MyDbContext(new DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>());
```

It gets the error of the parameter `connectionString` cannot be null. How to set up the DbContext in test project properly?

Comment: You just need to set options for it. As example this option are used to store db in the memory:
`var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase();
            var context = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

```
var dbOption = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
    .UseSqlServer("....")
    .Options;
```

Comment: For others looking, the other solutions are slightly more complete in that they initialize the context too!

Answer (score 10):

The [George Alexandria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5359302/george-alexandria)'s solutions work for me:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(); 
var context = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

The `UseInMemoryDatabase` extension method is included in [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory)

Comment: For those who use this more complete method, don't forget to either use 'context.dispose()' or a using bracket i.e. using (var context = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options)){ // Your code here}.

Comment: Do you have configuration using fluent API? It seems the ModelBuilder is no available for the OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) beucase it is supplied with DI from ASP.Net. Is there a way to supply the ModelBuilder for the DBContext in a testing project?

Answer (score 3):

EF 2.0 requires that all in-memory database are named, so be sure to name it like so:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("MyInMemoryDatabseName"); 
var context = new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```